# Save Audio to SD CARD

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

I have been looking to save an audio to SdCard.

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC) + "/AUDIO/");
        boolean success1;
        if (!dir.exists()) {

            MessageSystem("SAVING FOLDER: " + dir + " -- DON'T EXISTS ");

            //CASE NOT -  We create
            success1 = dir.mkdir();


            if (success1) {
                // Do something on success
                MessageSystem("foldersd: " + dir.toString() +  " CREATED!!");


            } else {
                // Do something else on failure
                MessageSystem("foldersd: " + dir.toString() +  " NOT CREATED!!");

            }

        }
```

I have tried to save also to:

```
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AUDIO/");
```

On both cases it worked but it saves to INTERNAL STORAGE. NEVER TO SD CARD

I used getExternalFilesDirs() to. But the user will loose the files if he uninstalls the app.

I don't want that.

How can I save the audios in a SD card public folder or create a new one.

Any times it creates into Internal Storage.

Any solution???

I tried with this and I could create a document in the SD CARD. And empty one. Now I would like to save a MediaRecorder audio into it. But I need the path. How can I get it?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("application/mpeg");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, audio_name);

        // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
        // the system file picker when your app creates the document.
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
```

Comment: It depends on the Android version used. But using SAF works for all versions above kitkat.

Comment: could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
public static final String DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION = "/sdcard/AudioRecording";

File dir = new File(DEFAULT_STORAGE_LOCATION);

if (!dir.exists()) {
try {
    dir.mkdirs();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("CallRecorder", "RecordService::makeOutputFile unable to create directory " + dir + ": " + e);
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CallRecorder was unable to create the directory " + dir + " to store recordings: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.show();
    return null;
}
} else {
if (!dir.canWrite()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "RecordService::makeOutputFile does not have write permission for directory: " + dir);
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CallRecorder does not have write permission for the directory directory " + dir + " to store recordings", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    t.show();
    return null;
}
```

2. you can get the sd card location by querying the system as,

   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

and don't forget to add the user permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: I have tried this! Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() as I said in my question;

I also tried this "/sdcard/AudioRecording" 

both save into internal storage!